# Comparing Two values in the same row of pandas dataframe with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two columns `r1` and `r2` in the pandas dataframe by row, essentially I want to return the 'red' when value in `r1` is greater than that of `r2` in the same row, while the outcome is that the comparison only returns `yellow` in the else condition even two values are provided.

Below is the dataset for reproducing the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan 
time_idx = pd.date_range('2021-01-05', periods=8, freq='3H')
r1 = np.concatenate([[nan,nan,nan],235,324,125,[nan,nan]], axis=None)
r2 = np.concatenate([114,nan,345,235,nan,125,178,324], axis=None)
df_r = pd.DataFrame({'r1': r1,'r2':r2},index =  time_idx) 
df_r["Light"]=['red' if df_r.loc[t,'r1'] > df_r.loc[t,'r2']
                  else 'yellow' for t in df_r.index]
print(df_r)
```

And here are the outputs:

```
                        r1     r2   Light
2021-01-05 00:00:00    NaN  114.0  yellow
2021-01-05 03:00:00    NaN    NaN  yellow
2021-01-05 06:00:00    NaN  345.0  yellow
2021-01-05 09:00:00  235.0  235.0  yellow
2021-01-05 12:00:00  324.0    NaN  yellow
2021-01-05 15:00:00  125.0  125.0  yellow
2021-01-05 18:00:00    NaN  178.0  yellow
2021-01-05 21:00:00    NaN  324.0  yellow
```

My question goes to as follows:

1. How can I achieve the goal intended while sticking at using list comprehension?

Thank you.

Comment: You have no rows where `r1 > r2` except for `r1=324` if you consider that `324 > NaN`. `125 > 125` is False because it's not 'greater than' but 'greater than or equal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have `red` where `r1==324`, replace `np.nan` by `-np.inf`:

```
df_r['Light'] = df_r['r1'].gt(df_r['r2'].fillna(-np.inf)) \
                          .replace({True: 'red', False: 'yellow'})
print(df)

# Output:
                        r1     r2   Light
2021-01-05 00:00:00    NaN  114.0  yellow
2021-01-05 03:00:00    NaN    NaN  yellow
2021-01-05 06:00:00    NaN  345.0  yellow
2021-01-05 09:00:00  235.0  235.0  yellow
2021-01-05 12:00:00  324.0    NaN     red
2021-01-05 15:00:00  125.0  125.0  yellow
2021-01-05 18:00:00    NaN  178.0  yellow
2021-01-05 21:00:00    NaN  324.0  yellow
```

[`.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) is equivalent to the operator `>`.

Comment: @lijch. Does it solve your problem?